# How to get name of a JValue object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json for parsing Json text. For a reason I need name of JToken or Jvalue object. As per example if **"ChoiceId":865** is JValue then I need to get **"ChoiceId"**. But I am trying it for few hours now but could not figure out how. How can I get that name ?

Thanks

EXAMPLE:
if this is the json file content:

```
{"ChoiceId":868,"Choice":"Post","Url":"/pst/goods"}
```

Then I can get ChoiceId value by using

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(hole);
JValue jvalue = (Jvalue)json["ChoiceId"];
string value = jvalue.Value;
```

But there is no property for getting the name ie."ChoiceId" . So my question is that how can I get it ?

Comment: Can you add some of your code to the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I've seen none of your code thus I'm spitballing, perhaps you're looking for [`JToken.Parent` and `JProperty`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)?

```
// Assumes token is JToken, search for the owning JProperty
var parentProperty = token.Ancestors<JProperty>()
                          .FirstOrDefault();

// alternatively, if you know it'll be a property:
var parentProperty = ((JProperty)token.Parent);

var name = parentProperty.Name;
```